# How to adjust number of ticks?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

output:

[image]

Now I need adjust number of ticks for `y` axis, like `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5`, or make it less, like `2,4,6`.

I tried to change `y0` and `dy` arguments nothing is changes:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    y0 = 0,
    dy = 50,
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    y0 = 0,
    dy = 50,
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

**Question:** How to adjust nuber of tiks for `y` axis for my first code?

Comment: Do you mean custom y-ticks or what? Do you mind to be a little more precise?

Comment: @rpanai Yes. Thank you for asking. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group',yaxis=dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = 1,
        dtick = 0.5
    ))
fig.show()
```

The trick here is to use the parameter - `yaxis` during the `update_layout`. Same goes for `xaxis` tick properties

[image]

Comment: I found a way to see all properties. Just write invalid property like `tickmodeee` instead of `tickmode` and after error message all properties will be listed.